# Resize a QQuickPaintedItem in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I use a custom QQuickPaintedItem to display a Qimage in QML.
I registered it using:

**main.cpp**

```
qmlRegisterType<ImageItem>("myextension", 1, 0, "ImageItem");
```

**ImageItem.h**

```
class ImageItem : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QImage image READ image WRITE setImage NOTIFY imageChanged)
public:
  ImageItem(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr);
  Q_INVOKABLE void setImage(const QImage &image);
  Q_INVOKABLE void resize(const int& width);
  void paint(QPainter *painter);
  QImage image() const;
signals:
  void imageChanged();
private:
  QImage current_image;
};
```

How can I resize QImage in QML for displaying purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didnt expect it would be that simple.

```
ImageItem {
  image: sqlImageData
  id: myIcon
  width: 50 //resizing
  height:50 //resizing
}
```